# What is 'System and compressed memory' and why is it using so much memory?

Tags: windows-10, memory

On Windows 10, There is a process `System and compressed memory`.

What is it and why is it using so much memory?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in the name,

> System and ***compressed memory***

A quick explanation of this can be found [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/08/18/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10525/)

> In Windows 10, we have added a new concept in the Memory Manager
>   called a compression store, which is an in-memory collection of
>   compressed pages. This means that when Memory Manager feels memory
>   pressure, it will compress unused pages instead of writing them to
>   disk. This reduces the amount of memory used per process, allowing
>   Windows 10 to maintain more applications in physical memory at a time.
>   This also helps provide better responsiveness across Windows 10. The
>   compression store lives in the System process’s working set. Since the
>   system process holds the store in memory, its working set grows larger
>   exactly when memory is being made available for other processes. This
>   is visible in Task Manager and the reason the System process appears
>   to be consuming more memory than previous releases.

Remember that unused RAM is of no benefit to you. Not having to write to a page file and read it back again from a significantly slower storage device is a faster method of memory management. Note that if you do need this RAM, the system will release it or continue to use a page file as required.

In short, this is expected behaviour of Windows 10, not a bug, and will provide speed benefits over simply throwing everything into a page file.

Comment: The only thing I see in my PC because of this process is other programs getting hung due to lack of memory :(